# Error 401: Invalid Client. Google API with Postman

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postman, google-oauth

My company's client organization would like us to do data pulls on their campaign data using AWS Lambda so that our digital marketing analysts can analyze the data and use predictive modeling (data is stored in AWS data lake). However, I'd like to pre-test API calls  using Postman. We will be using the Google Campaign Manager API (GCM 360).

> When I try to generate a New Access token in Postman, I get this *Error No OAuth Client was found*. I made sure that the client secret values,scope, token URL,Auth URL, and callback url were correct and their values matched Google API Playground.
>
> I then looked at the Postman log trace and I am seeing an incorrect
> Client ID that does not match what's Postman nor the CGM 360 API
> credentials.  Here are the screen scrapes and not the client ID in the
> postman trace log does not match what's defined in GCM360's OAuth
> credentials page. ***Are these 2 completely different client IDs***?
> See screen scrapes of the GCM360 API's credentials page, Postman Authorization page, and the error message below.
> Thanks:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When encountering an "Error: No OAuth Client was found" message in Postman while trying to generate a new access token, there are a few potential reasons for this issue:

1. Incorrect Client ID or Client Secret

Double-check that the Client ID and Client Secret values entered in Postman match the credentials provided by the Google Campaign Manager API. Any mismatch in these values can result in authentication errors.

2. Authorization Configuration:

Ensure that the authorization configuration in Postman is correctly set up. Verify that the token URL, authorization URL, and callback URL are accurate and aligned with the Google Campaign Manager API's requirements.

3. Scope:

Confirm that the scope you're requesting in Postman matches the scope defined in the Google Campaign Manager API credentials. The scope determines the access permissions granted by the access token.

It's important to cross-check all the details, such as Client ID, Client Secret, URLs, and scope, between the Google Campaign Manager API credentials and your Postman configuration. Any discrepancies can lead to authentication failures.

Comment: Thanks @Mohsin, there was one main issue that I had which was  that I in attempting to access the 3 scopes for GCM 360, somehow authorization didn't like the scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfatrafficking. When I removed that form the list of scopes it worked. No more 401 Error.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT

Comment: When I ran this using Postman Web version, I got a 401 and later an access block because of one of my scops which was invalid. Here is the message the popup error dialog gave me: Some requested scopes were invalid. {valid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfareporting, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ddmconversions], invalid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfatraffiking]} Learn more about this error. So I had to removing the DFA traffiking scope. I wonder if this needs readonly permissions? I will try to add that.